# array to php variable

Tags: php, arrays

I need to save 'Date' in array to php variable. (get_headers)
There are 2 types of array.

Type1

```
Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.1 302 Object Moved
    [Content-Type] => Array
        (
            [0] => text/html
            [1] => text/html;charset=UTF-8
        )
    [1] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    [Date] => Thu, 27 Jun 2013 06:50:37 GMT
```

Type2

```
Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
    [Date] => Array
        (
            [0] => Thu, 27 Jun 2013 06:50:27 GMT
            [1] => Thu, 27 Jun 2013 06:41:59 GMT
        )
```

Here is how I slice:

```
$arr = array();
$arr = get_headers($url,1);

$date_variable = $arr[Date];

if($date_variable == 'Array'){
        $date = $arr[Date][0];
}
else {
    $date = $arr[Date];
}
```

My slicing is very ugly.. and $date_variable == 'Array' doesn't work..

Comment: if `is_array($date_variable)` is what you want, maybe?

Comment: oh.. that was simple.. Thanks !!!

Comment: take care with `$arr[Date];` it should be `$arr['Date'];` as far as I know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$date = is_array($arr['Date']) ? $arr['Date'][0] : $arr['Date'];
```

Comment: @newworroo notice the quoted `'Date'` as opposed to your `Date`

Comment: @SteveTaylor the same notice goes to you too :)

Answer (score 0):

This may helps to you

```
$arr = array();
$arr = get_headers($url,1);

$date_variable = $arr['Date'];

//check the array like this
if(is_array($date_variable)){

    $date = $date_variable[0];
}
else {

    $date = $date_variable;
}
```